# How do I extract the last string of a csv file and append it to the other?

Tags: matlab, octave

I have csv file of many rows, each having 101 columns, with the 101th column being a char, while the rest of the columns are doubles. Eg.

1,-2.2,3 ... 98,99,100,N

I implemented a filter to operate on the numbers and wrote the result in a different file, but now I need to map the last column of my old csv to my new csv. how should I approach this?

I did the original loading using loadcsv but that didn't seem to load the character so how should I proceed?

Comment: `loadcsv` does not exist in MATLAB or Octave you meant `csvread` ?

Answer (score 0):

In MATLAB there are many ways to do it, this answer expands on the use of `tables`:

#### Input

`test.csv`

```
1,2,5,A
2,3,5,G
5,6,8,C
8,9,7,T
```

`test2.csv`

```
1,2,1.2
2,3,8
5,6,56
8,9,3
```

#### Script

```
t1 = readtable('test.csv'); % Read the csv file
lastcol = t{:,end}; % Extract the last column
t2 = readtable('test2.csv'); % Read the second csv file
t2.addedvar = lastcol; % Add the last column of the first file to the table from the second file
writetable(t2,'test3.csv','Delimiter',',','WriteVariableNames',false) % write the new table in a file
```

Note that `test3.csv` is a new file but you could also overwrite `test2.csv`

`'WriteVariableNames',false` allows you to write the csv file without the headers of the table.

#### Output

`test3.csv`

```
1,2,1.2,A
2,3,8,G
5,6,56,C
8,9,3,T
```